# Unexpected indentation when return in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, function, fastapi, indentation

when I try to return but I got an error in 2nd **return signup_result** & **return login_result**
https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md#reportUndefinedVariable

```
"return" can be used only within a functionPylance
```

here is utils.py

```
class CognitoResponse(object):
    def __init__(self, access_token, refresh_token, cognito_user_id=None):
        self.access_token = access_token
        self.refresh_token = refresh_token
        self.cognito_user_id = cognito_user_id

    def cognito_signup(username: str, password: str):

        return signup_result

# In order to get the ID and authenticate, use AWS Cognito
client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name=os.environ.get('COGNITO_REGION_NAME'))
try:
    response = client.sign_up(
        ClientId=os.environ.get('COGNITO_USER_CLIENT_ID'),
        Username=username,
        Password=password
    )
except Exception as e: # Generally, will trigger upon non-unique email
    raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=f"{e}")

user_sub = response['UserSub']

# This will confirm user registration as an admin without a confirmation code
client.admin_confirm_sign_up(
    UserPoolId=os.environ.get('USER_POOL_ID'),
    Username=username,
)

# Now authenticate the user and return the tokens
auth_response = client.initiate_auth(
    ClientId=os.environ.get('COGNITO_USER_CLIENT_ID'),
    AuthFlow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
    AuthParameters={
        'USERNAME': username,
        'PASSWORD': password
    }
)
access_token = auth_response['AuthenticationResult']['AccessToken']
refresh_token = auth_response['AuthenticationResult']['RefreshToken']

signup_result = utils.CognitoResponse(
    access_token=access_token,
    refresh_token=refresh_token,
    cognito_user_id=user_sub
)
return signup_result

def cognito_login(username: str, password: str):

    return login_result

client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name=os.environ.get('COGNITO_REGION_NAME'))
# Authenticate the user and return the tokens
try:
    auth_response = client.initiate_auth(
        ClientId=os.environ.get('COGNITO_USER_CLIENT_ID'),
        AuthFlow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
        AuthParameters={
            'USERNAME': username,
            'PASSWORD': password
        }
    )
except Exception as e: # Generally, will trigger upon wrong email/password
    raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=f"{e}")

access_token = auth_response['AuthenticationResult']['AccessToken']
refresh_token = auth_response['AuthenticationResult']['RefreshToken']
login_result = utils.CognitoResponse(
    access_token=access_token,
    refresh_token=refresh_token
)
return login_result
```

I also try to tab 2 times to  avoid indentation error in **return signup_result** & **return login_result** but still got the same error Unexpected indentationPylance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def cognito_login(username: str, password: str):

    return login_result

client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name=os.environ.get('COGNITO_REGION_NAME'))

# Authenticate the user and return the tokens
try:
    auth_response = client.initiate_auth(
        ClientId=os.environ.get('COGNITO_USER_CLIENT_ID'),
        AuthFlow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
        AuthParameters={
            'USERNAME': username,
            'PASSWORD': password
        }
    )
    # lots more code...
```

The `cognito_login()` function contains only one line of code `return login_result` because that is the only code that is indented underneath the function.

The rest of the following code is not indented underneath the function, therefore it is not part of the function.

Indentation is very important in Python.

Your code should likely be formatted as follows:

```
def cognito_login(username: str, password: str):

    #return login_result remove this as the next lines of code need to run

    client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name=os.environ.get('COGNITO_REGION_NAME'))

    # Authenticate the user and return the tokens
    try:
        auth_response = client.initiate_auth(
            ClientId=os.environ.get('COGNITO_USER_CLIENT_ID'),
            AuthFlow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
            AuthParameters={
                'USERNAME': username,
                'PASSWORD': password
            }
        )
        # lots more code...
```